# Error while connecting with SnowSQL Failed to establish a new connection:

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, connectivity

G'day everyone, wanted to learn a bit about snowflake, read through documentation, decided to try it out. Created test account, installed snowsql on my desktop and trying to connect... basics... and im stuck. I can connect via browser with this account, hence user/pass combo is correct.

````
Password:
250003 (n/a): Failed to get the response. Hanging? method: post, url: https://DD73453.eu-central-1.snowflakecomputing.com.snowflakecomputing.com:443/session/v1/login-request?request_id=c4f4fc93-9381-4cbd-8108-70daba148603&request_guid=fbe2973d-2ccd-4337-97c2-01611e2e4278
If the error message is unclear, enable logging using -o log_level=DEBUG and see the log to find out the cause. Contact support for further help.
Goodbye!

C:\Windows\system32>snowsql -a https://DD73453.eu-central-1.snowflakecomputing.com -u GREGTEST
Password:
250003 (n/a): Failed to execute request: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='https', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: //DD73453.eu-central-1.snowflakecomputing.com.snowflakecomputing.com:443/session/v1/login-request?request_id=218d9545-d758-44a2-b29d-d6d90fc3fcfc (Caused by NewConnectionError('<snowflake.connector.vendored.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x000001DC7A5AB710>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed',))
If the error message is unclear, enable logging using -o log_level=DEBUG and see the log to find out the cause. Contact support for further help.
Goodbye!```
````

Answer (score 3):

The account (-a parameter) should be just:

DD73453.eu-central-1

Comment: Dear NickW, Big thanks, i thought it will be something simple :)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of https://DD73453.eu-central-1.snowflakecomputing.com use only "DD73453.eu-central-1"

Below should work

snowsql -a DD73453.eu-central-1 -u username